# Scroll to end in a PullToRefreshListView

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

How do I programmatically upon inserting new items to a PullToRefreshListView scroll so that the last item is visible?

Here is some code:

```
listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(someAdapter);
```

And I would like to do:

```
listView.scrollToEnd();
```

or

```
someAdapter.scrollToEnd();
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the TranscriptMode on a ListView to have it always scroll to the bottom when new content is added

`listView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);`

You can also use

`listView.scrollTo(0, listView.getHeight());`

Comment: Thanks, it would work for a normal ListView I guess, but for a PullToRefreshListView I had to do:  listView.getRefreshableView().setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);