# PullToRefreshListView scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am using the PullToRefreshListView library from [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). When new content is added I am trying to have the view scroll to the bottom. Nothing seems to work. I tried everything mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502365/scroll-to-end-in-a-pulltorefreshlistview) and used listView.scrollTo(), listView.getRefreshableView().smoothScrollToPosition() etc. but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same library, scrolling like this always works for me.

```
listView.getRefreshableView().smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount());
```

If not works, put your code here, something you are doing is wrong...